# Prove that $2^n + 3^n < 4^n$

Tags: induction

> Prove that $$2^n + 3^n < 4^n$$ using induction such that $n$ belongs to the natural numbers, $n \ge 2$.

BC: $n = 2$

$$2^2 + 3^2 < 4^2$$

$$13<16$$

IH: assume true that for $k$ belonging to the naturals that $2^k + 3^k < 4^k$. For $k + 1$

$$2^{k+1} + 3^{k+1} < 4^{k+1}$$

I am stuck after this point.

Comment: Hint: $4^{k+1} - 3^{k+1} - 2^{k+1} = 4(4^k - 3^k - 2^k) + (4-3)3^k + (4-2) 2^k$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$2^{k+1} + 3^{k+1}  = 2 \cdot 2^k + 3 \cdot 3^k  < 4 \cdot 2^k + 4 \cdot 3^k  = 4(2^k + 3^k) < 4 \cdot 4^k = 4^{k+1}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$
2^{k + 1} + 3^{k + 1}
= 2 \cdot 2^k + 3 \cdot 3^k
< 3\cdot 2^k + 3 \cdot 3^k.
$$